# Exception handling in python file i/O

Tags: python

Python newbie here and am running into some weird behavior in my code.

I am trying to write some data to a file. I print the length of the data to be about 50k before I call the following block of code. The data is a pdf file I got over the internet. And its a valid pdf.

When I call the function F() described below, I get the exception message printed in function F and not in the actual place it fails.

In the code below, in the function write_to_disk() I see the second print and the execution directly jumps to the exception handler in the calling function F(). I cannot figure out why this is happening. On disk I see the file is created but the size is 0.

Can some look at the code below and may be guess what could be happening?
If I am catching exceptions in the write_to_disk() function how is it possible for it to jump out of the function completely?

EDIT: Thanks for kobejohn, turns out the excetion object does not have a errno variable. Getting rid of it made the print appear. But the bigger problem still exists. I see a failure with no way to find out why its failing. How do I get the error message here?

```
def write_to_disk(self, pathToWrite, pdfFileData):
    try:
        print 'Here `1.1'
        fd = open(pathToWrite, "w+")
        print 'Here `2.1'
        fd.write(pdfFileData)
        print 'Here 3.1'
        fd.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print 'file cannot be opened ' + pathToWrite + e.errno
```

This function is inturn called by another function F which is like this -

```
def F(self, url):

    pathWrite = get_path_to_use()
    pdfData = get_pdf_data(url)

    try:
        writetodisk(pathToWrite, pdfData)
    except Exception as e:
        print 'Did I jump directly to here?' + e.errno
```

Here is the out put of the program. I did not think it will add anything because I see nothing if any use. In fact I get the same output even when running it in pdb.

```
Here `1.1
Here `2.1
Did I jump directly to here?
```

Comment: could you paste the output of your program?

Comment: It is worth noting that when working with files in Python, you should [use the `with` statement](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lRaKmobSXF4) to ensure that in this kind of situation, you close the file, even if there is an exception. Catching `Exception` instead of a specific exception is also a really bad idea - you'll catch things you didn't mean to, leading to misleading error messages, or odd behavior.

Comment: I bet your error is bubbling up because you are causing a further exception in your except block. I don't think exceptions have an "errno" attribute. I.e. try getting rid of `e.errno`.

Comment: @Lattyware - thanks I will read up on it

Comment: @kobejohn - That makes sense. How do I get the error in this case?

Comment: @kobejohn you are correct. getting rid of e.errno makes the print appear. For some reason Eclipse autocomplete prompts errno. I assumed it exists and never questioned it.

Comment: Get rid of all the exception handling and actually read the exception.

Comment: I'm guessing your PDF data is Unicode and it is raising a UnicodeEncode error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just bubbling as we mentioned in the comments and Alexander said. Use this code to see how it can work (no errors, but that was just a nasty surprise you got with exceptions).

```
def f(url):
    path_to_write = 'test.dat'
    pdf_data = 'asdf'
    try:
        write_to_disk(path_to_write, pdf_data)
    except Exception as e:
        print 'Did I jump directly to here?\n' + str(e)


def write_to_disk(path_to_write, pdf_data):
    try:
        print 'Here `1.1'
        with open(path_to_write, "w+") as fd:
            print 'Here `2.1'
            fd.write(pdf_data)
    except Exception as e:
        print 'file cannot be opened ' + path_to_write


f('fake_url')
```

Some areas to make your code safer / more standard:

- do as little as possible inside a try block. try to isolate the code that you are worried might raise an error
- same rule for the except block. don't do anything strange there.
- as someone else mentioned, using a `with` block is a more standard and readable way to work with a file.
- other minor things with function and variable names you can see where I have changed things in the code above. google PEP 8 for more.

Answer (score 2):

Your first exception handler tries to build a string by concatenating another string and an `int` (`e.errno`) which causes it (the `print` statement) to throw an exception itself (which is then caught by the outer exception handler).

Comment: Turns out I have to get rid of the errno for this to work. How do you handle or see IO errors in your code?

Comment: Why not use formatting: print "Exception thrown: %d" % e.errno

Comment: The exception object does not have errno variable at all for me to use

Comment: Consider using str(e) instead